# How to return SignalRMessage inside async method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await, signalr

Hi I am working on azure function with SignalR. I have one method in azure function to push some SignalR messages. My function looks like below:

```
[FunctionName("samplefunction")]
public static async Task<SignalRMessage> PushSuccess(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] DataResponseSuccess DataResponseSuccess,
    ILogger log,
    [SignalR(HubName = "myhub")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
    HttpRequest req)
{
    var data = await Authenticated(req, log);
    if (data == "UnauthorizedResult")
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Authentication failed: at {DateTime.UtcNow}");
    }

    return signalRMessages.AddAsync(
       new SignalRMessage
       {
           UserId = "",
           Target = "myhub",
           Arguments = new[] { DataResponseSuccess }
       });
}
```

Recently I added `await Authenticated(req, log);` method and made method as `async Task<SignalRMessage>`. After making these changes I started getting below error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.threading.Task.Task to
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService.SignalRMessage.

Can someone help me to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi No that is not working

Answer (score 1):

> Try this!

```
var message = new SignalRMessage
{
   UserId = "",
   Target = "myhub",
   Arguments = new[] {DataResponseSuccess}
};

signalRMessages.Add(message);

if(signalRMessages.SaveChangesAsync()) return message;

throw new HubException("Failed!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
var message = new SignalRMessage
{
   UserId = "",
   Target = "myhub",
   Arguments = new[] {DataResponseSuccess}
};

await signalRMessages.AddAsync(message);
return message;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed method signature to public static async Task<Task>  and this worked for me. But is this correct way to do this?